# How to get first and second latest dates in a datetime field

Tags: mysql

I have a table

```
id   Name        date_time             package
1     abc    2016-02-25 11:29:00          0
2     xyz    2016-02-25 11:29:00          0
3     abc    2016-02-24 11:29:00          1
4     xyz    2016-02-24 11:29:00          1
5     abc    2016-02-23 11:29:00          1
6     xyz    2016-02-23 11:29:00          1
```

my result would be a virtual table that contains the result in the form of

```
name     latest_date           latest_date1
 abc        2016-02-25 11:29:00     2016-02-24 11:29:00 
 xyz        2016-02-25 11:29:00    2016-02-24 11:29:00
```

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application level code.

Comment: @Jens even i don't have any idea for doing this problem

Comment: You want to print the two lastest dates ?

Comment: It's also unclear what you are after. The data set is too small to be representative of the problem.

Comment: @Strawberry the dataset is too large that contains around 5000 record

Comment: Pathetic. Presumably there's some compromise between 6 rows and 5000 rows, that would effectively communicate the problem. 12 is usually enough.

Comment: @NAIT ya right want to print the two lastest dates

Comment: @jens what i tried is

Comment: All I know is when @Strawberry gets his gold in mysql, the fun *better* begin

Comment: @Drew Should the power ever be afforded me, I promise to use it benevolently!

Comment: In that case all my upvotes were in vain! j/k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a row number based on the descending order of `date_time` for each group of `Name`. Then select rn = 1 for `latest_date` and rn = 2 for `latest_date1`

**Query**

```
select t.Name as table_name,
max(case when t.rn = 1 then t.date_time end) as latest_date,
max(case when t.rn = 2 then t.date_time end) as latest_date1
from (
  select id, name, date_time, 
  (
    case name when @curA 
    then @curRow := @curRow + 1 
    else @curRow := 1 and @curA := name end 
  ) + 1 as rn 
  from your_table_name t, 
  (select @curRow := 1, @curA := '') r 
order by name, date_time desc
)t
group by t.Name;
```

[**SQL Fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4bfba8/1)